# Open new view controller page according to value chosen from UIPickerView (Swift 4)

Tags: swift, button, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

I would like to add a function in my app where the user has to choose a category from a UIPickerView and upon clicking a button, the program would open the view selected from the categories in the UIPickerView. For example, if one of the chosen options on the UIPickerView is "About Page", I would like to have a program that would open the "About Page" upon a click of the button.

This is what the UI would look like.[image]

But instead of the states - I would have the categories, I'm not sure how to set the values in the UIPickerView and open specific views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `UIPickerViewDelegate` method and give each VC a stroryboard Identifier

```
var lastId:String?

var ids = ["secondVC","thirdVC"] // picker data source and identifier names 

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, 
        didSelectRow row: Int, 
         inComponent component: Int) {
   lastId = ids[row]
}

@IBAction func goClicked(_ sender:UIButton) {
    if let id = lastId {
      let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:id)!
      self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) // or push
    }
    else {
      // select a vc alert
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, the ids could be segue identifiers to be used with `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.

Comment: @vacawama yes would be another alternative the op can use instead of push/present

Comment: @Sh_Khan - Thank You so much for your help - I think I understand the code - but I'm quite new to the UIPickerView idea - would you be kind enough to help me implement the UIPickerViewDelegate method, please?

Comment: look it's in answer **didSelectRow**

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the picker view programmatically - which I recommend the most - this solution should work for you:

```js
class MyViewController : UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {
    
    let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    let titles = ["view1", "view2"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        
        view.addSubview(pickerView)
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        return titles[row]
    }
    
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if row == 0 {
            let view1 = viewController1()
            self.present(view1, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        if row == 1 {
            let view2 = viewController2()
            self.present(view2, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
}

class viewController1 : UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}

class viewController2 : UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

hope that this works for you too ;)

Comment: Thank you so much - would you please explain why you recommend me to add it programmatically and not by using a storyboard identifier?

Comment: Because you have a better overview on what’s happening in your code and you can change things faster with the code than with the storyboard. It‘s also more recommended if you want to get a job as AppDeveloper because the big companies like Instagram and Facebook are all writing code instead of using the storyboard because it’s also easier for more people to work on code than changing every time something in the storyboard. Hope that this explains it well enough 